# Coping with Asperger's in the workplace

Tags: io-psychology, aspergers

People with Asperger's Syndrome (AS) are often highly intelligent and are capable to complete their studies and do well in jobs where they can operate solo. Adding a person with AS to a team can cause considerable stress at the workfloor which may be justified by the extraordinary skills of the employee with AS.

Are there any strategies for teams (or individuals) to cope with, learn to utilize, their team member with AS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work with people who have Asperger's Syndrome every day and have had no major problems at all.  The reason is that I do indeed follow some documented strategies, particularly those outlined in ["Working with a Person with Asperger’s Syndrome"](http://www.amaze.org.au/uploads/2011/08/Fact-Sheet-Working-with-a-Person-with-Aspergers-Syndrome-Aug-11.pdf) (Autism Victoria, 2007). A brief list of strategies suggested by that document suggest that workers with Asperger's Syndrome need:

- consistency 
- predictability
- a calm and controlled supervisor (this also applies to coworkers)
- an organised workplace

Most of all, don't make a big deal of their condition, just be aware of what is needed.